# Bootstrap If Statement for Rank System

Tags: php, image, twitter-bootstrap, rank

I'm trying to add a statement in Bootstrap where basically if a users post is more than 10 (for example) then a rank image. I did have the statement below:

```
{if $userArray.UserPosts > 0}
                                            <span id="headerWelcomeRank">
                                            {if $userArray.UserPosts < 10}
                                                {$translate->__("Cadet")}
                                            {elseif $userArray.UserPosts < 25}
                                                {$translate->__("Ensign")}
                                            {elseif $userArray.UserPosts < 50}
                                                {$translate->__("Lt JG")}
                                            {elseif $userArray.UserPosts < 100}
                                                {$translate->__("Lt")}
                                            {elseif $userArray.UserPosts < 200}
                                                {$translate->__("Lt Commander")}
                                            {elseif $userArray.UserPosts >= 300}
                                                {$translate->__("Commander")}
                                            {elseif $userArray.UserPosts >= 400}
                                                {$translate->__("Captain")} 
                                            {/if}
                                            </span>
                                        {/if}
```

But that didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What language are you writing in? Your posts is tagged as PHP so this is your code in PHP:

```
<?php
$userPosts = $userArray["UserPosts"]; // Or however you get their post count.
if ($userPosts > 0) {
    echo "<span id=\"headerWelcomeRank\">";
    if ($userPosts < 10) {
        $translate->__("Cadet")
    } elseif ($userPosts < 25) {
        $translate->__("Ensign");
    } elseif ($userPosts < 50) {
        $translate->__("Lt JG");
    } elseif ($userPosts < 100) {
        $translate->__("Lt");
    } elseif ($userPosts < 200) {
        $translate->__("Lt Commander");
    } elseif ($userPosts >= 300) {
        $translate->__("Commander");
    } elseif ($userPosts >= 400) {
        $translate->__("Captain");
    }
    echo "</span>";
}
```

If your problem persists, could provide what your actual output is and confirm if you are trying to use PHP or Smarty or something else that would be great.